# Vue 2 custom component valus is always "undefined"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to create a custom component in Vue.

This is the simplest component I could come up with and the `value` prop is ALWAYS undefined.

```
<template>
    <div>
        - {{ value }} -
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['value'],

        mounted() {
            console.log(this.value);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Not doing anything special when I call it:

```
<el-text-group v-model="testVar"></el-text-group>

{{ testVar }}
```

The variable `testVar` shows fine, but the custom component shows nothing?

I've followed a bunch of tutorials and the official docs:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Form-Input-Components-using-Custom-Events

I'm using latest Vue 2.4.2. It seems to work fine with Vue 2.2.x.

I've actually had this issue months ago but thought I would wait to see if something got fixed. But testing again now and the issue is still there. No idea, seems very basic, not sure if there is some change on how to do this?

**FILES:**

**app.js**

```
var component = require('./components/App.vue');

component.router = Vue.router;

new Vue(component).$mount('#app');
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        Hello

        <hr/>

        <test-cpt v-model="testVar"></test-cpt>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                testVar: 'test'
            };
        },

        components: {
            testCpt: require('./TestCpt.vue')
        }
    }
</script>
```

**TestCpt.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        - {{ value }} -
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['value']
    }
</script>
```

Comment: what do you expect `value` would be in the code you posted?

Comment: It's not a Vue problem. https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/zdemVW?editors=1010

Comment: @JaromandaX testVar shows "test" just fine, but in the custom component (input) it's all empty and shows `undefined` in console.

Comment: @Bert hmm, something with webpack possibly?

Comment: Show how you are using the component.

Comment: @Bert exactly how it shows in the example. Note a single line switch from `2.4.2` to `2.2.6` and it works.

Comment: [Works fine with webpack](https://codesandbox.io/s/1qr8rqp1yl) as well. What I meant by show how it's used is show where you import it, register it, etc. Essentially the parent component.

Comment: @Bert I set up an isolated test and seems to work so I just removed my node_modules folder and reinstalled and voila it works. Anyway, thanks for taking the time to help me.

Comment: I figured it must be something like that. Glad you got it worked out!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Removing node_modules and reinstalling seemed to fix it.